# imageview listview

Tags: java, android, arrays, image, android-listview

I've got a question.

I've made a database (Array) with different like, name, id, type.
Also I've made string that reads the name (name is a string:

```
public static String[] getAllPokemonsInStrings() {
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    for(Pokemon p : Pokemon.values()){
        if(p.getName() != null){
            items.add(p.getName());
        }
    }
    return items.toArray(new String[]{});
}
```

Here's the bit that creates it:

```
public class Test3 extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label,      Types.getAllPokemonsInStrings() ));

    }
}
```

And the xml per row:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout">  

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/sprite"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="96dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/sprite"
        android:src="@drawable/p002" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"  
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/label"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:padding="10dip"
            android:textSize="16dip"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Is there a way to change the imageresource (which is an int) doing that per row, loading it from the array?

Comment: The plural of pokemon is pokemon without an s :P

Comment: Eh, I named my List `pokemons` to make it distinct from the current `pokemon` object. No harm, no foul :P

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. You gonna need to create your own adapter class though and Override `getView()`. I would recommend you read this [tutorial](http://developerlife.com/tutorials/?p=327) on how to create a custom adapter.